# System Access violation exception:Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c++, winapi

I have CAN Dll program for my application, which was separately used. Now I have included the Drivers program into my application Program and I am having this error `System Access Violation Exception:Attempted to read or write protected memory`. What is error for? I am attaching the Dll code and Application code which is throwing this error.

The CAN Dll Code

```
int receive_data(unsigned char *data_output, int *MsgId, XLportHandle g_xlPortHandle){
    XLstatus xlStatus, xlStatus_new;
    XLevent xlEvent;
    unsigned int msgsrx=RECEIVE_EVENT_SIZE;
    char *local_data ="11111111";
    DWORD status;

    xlStatus_new = xlSetNotification(g_xlPortHandle, &h, 1);

    WaitForSingleObject(h,1);
    xlStatus = XL_SUCCESS;

    while(!xlStatus){
        msgsrx = RECEIVE_EVENT_SIZE;
        xlStatus = xlReceive(g_xlPortHandle, &msgsrx, &xlEvent);---------->Here is the error
        if ( xlStatus!=XL_ERR_QUEUE_IS_EMPTY ) {
            memcpy(data_output,xlEvent.tagData.msg.data,8);
            *MsgId = xlEvent.tagData.msg.id;
            return 0;
        }

        else{
            return XL_ERR_QUEUE_IS_EMPTY;
        }
    }
}
```

So this program builded successfully and while executing it I am getting the error as

```
Receive thread quit Unexpectedly
system Access violation Exception:Attempted to read or write protected memory.This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt at
xlreceive(int32,Uint32*,s_xl_event*)
at receive_data(Byte*data_output,int32*MsgId,Int32 g_xlPortHandle).
```

Comment: Perhaps you're supposed to supply the `xlEvent.tagData.msg.data` buffer? Does xlEvent need initialization?

Comment: but xlEvent.tagData.msg.data is copied into the buffer data_output.

Comment: You're not checking for errors on xlSetNotification or WaitForSingleObject.  Either or both could be failing, which would likely lead to a crash downstream.  Also, I see no declaration for h.  What is it and where is it defined?

Comment: h is the XLhandle which I have declared as global varible.It is the notification handle for the receive queue.

Comment: Some structures/classes require a buffer to be set into them, for example `xlEvent.tagData.msg.data = YourBufferThatYouHaveAllocated;` ... it would explain your error, but I don't actually know the xlEvent structure/format/design.

Answer (score 0):

I had same/similar errors caused by the lack of initialization of the XLevent struct.

That can be achieved with an initialization list:

```
XLevent xlEvent = {0};
```

or if you are already using dynamic memory management a memset will do the trick:

```
XLevent xlEvent;
memset(&xlEvent, 0, sizeof(xlEvent));
```

These are partially equivalent (the output will be the same).
For more info please check this thread:
[what is the difference between struct {0} and memset 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031727/what-is-the-difference-between-struct-0-and-memset-0)